# Where to save jar's for project?

Tags: java

I'm knew to the stackoverflow community so forgive me if I'm doing this wrong.

I have a java project that I'm building [using itellij], where I am using an API with a jar I downloaded. What is the best way to add the jar to the project so a user (or another programmer) can just open it and not have to download the jar? Or if I was to deploy the program, how would I include the jar so it could be run with the necessary jars?
Currently I have made a separate folder named jars and load it from there.

Comment: Your basic export should have the ability to compile all used libraries into the final jar. This blog post is a little old but should have the details you need for IntelliJ: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/ In Eclipse, you would export a runnable jar with the option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" selected.

Comment: ah that make's sense. clears up a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use maven for solve these problems.

See this tutorial, if you are interested in maven: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: I'll take a look at it guys thanks! Also, I've been dumping it on to GitHub. Would Maven take care of that? (i.e. if I cloned it to a different computer)

Comment: I use GIT via terminal. Looking quickly after your question, I found this link. https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-providers-git/maven-scm-provider-jgit/
But I recommend using via terminal (Git Bash). See the git book, i recomend: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2